# objects in a c# arraylist

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm coming from a Javascript background which possibly is a good thing although so far it's proving to be a bad thing.

In Javascript, I have:

```
function doStuff(){
    var temp = new Array();
    temp.push(new marker("bday party"));
    alert(temp[0].whatsHappening); // 'bday party' would be alerted
}

function marker(whatsHappening) {
    this.whatsHappening = whatsHappening;
}
```

I would now like to do the same thing in C#. I have set up a class:

```
class marker
{
    public string whatsHappening;

    public marker(string w) {
        whatsHappening = w;
    }
}
```

and add a new object, but I can't seem to call the data in the same way:

```
ArrayList markers = new ArrayList();

markers.Add(new marker("asd"));
string temp = markers[0].whatsHappening; // This last bit isn't allowed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead:

```
List<marker> markers = new List<marker>();
markers.Add(new marker("asd"));
string temp = markers[0].whatsHappening;
```

Answer (score 4):

ArrayList is weakly typed. That means, all items in the array are objects. You need to cast them to your class:

```
string temp = ((marker)markers[0]).whatsHappening;
```

You should use a `List<marker>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To use it from an `ArrayList`, you must first cast it to the appropriate type. `ArrayList` stores items as `object`.

```
var item = (marker)markers[0];
// item.Foo is now accessible
```

However, assuming you're using a version of C# released since 2005 (ie., C# 2.0+), you will be better off using `List<T>`, where `T` is the type of the object. It's strongly typed, can *only* store items of type `T`, and does not require casts to perform operations.

```
List<marker> markers = new List<marker>();
markers.Add(new marker()); // legal
markers.Add(1); // not legal, but would be allowed with ArrayList
```

`List<T>` is available in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

---

Unrelated, since you're new to C#, learn the conventions of the language that virtually all C# developers adhere to. A few basic ones: class names, properties, methods are PascalCased, private members, parameters, local variables are camelCased, and class data is exposed as properties, not as publicly accessible fields.

```
public class Marker
{
    public string WhatsHappening { get; set; } // exposed as property 

    string foo; // member field, is implicitly private

    public void DoFrobbing(Bar thingToFrob)
    {
        int localVariable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` holds a list of `Object`s. Try to use the generic `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`:

```
List<marker> markers = new List<marker>();
```